# Pass on a map value as string to an argument list

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

AWS Glue Job takes a list of default arguments. I need to read a YAML config file containing all these parameters. Some parameters are nested YAML and I need to pass on the nested value as a string, and I'm not sure if that's possible in Terraform.

```
resource "aws_glue_job" "glue_jobs" {
 name = xxx
 default_arguments = zipmap([ for key, value in local.param_config_file["default-params"] : "${key}" ], [ for key, value in local.param_config_file["default-params"] : value ])
}
```

Config file structure:

```
job-description: Initial load
enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log: true
enable-metrics: false
enable-spark-ui: true
job-bookmark-option: job-bookmark-disable
job-language: python

connectors:
  conn-name-1: xxx
  conn-name-2: xxx

script-file: path/to/script_file

default-params:
  arg1: rds_db
  arg2: rds_cat_name

   schemas:
     schema_1: schema_name_1
     schema_2: schema_name_2

  rds_input_table_list: 
      - database: db_name
        schema: schema_name
        table: table_name
      - database: db_name
        schema: schema_name
        table: table_name
  rds_output_table: output_table
  # # --SQL
  sql: |
    This is the SQL definition for each job
  sql_type: sparksql
```

The zipmap solution works only if the value of the key has a single value. For example: Key = "value"
But, when the value is a nested map, let's take "schemas" as an example which has a map value of

```
 schemas:
   schema_1: schema_name_1
   schema_2: schema_name_2
```

Then, how can I pass this on as a string to the value of the argument?

```
argument_schema = string(         
                          schema_1: schema_name_1
                          schema_2: schema_name_2
                        )
```

or a similar approach.

In other words, how can I convert an object/list of objects to a string and pass it on as a single string value of one variable.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? What is the context of your zipmap? Can you provide the actual resource code where zipmap is used?

Comment: The above code works for non-nested values only.
Key = Value
Key = Value
But, if the Value is a nested object itself, I do not know how to pass on the whole value map as a string. For example:
Key = Value
Key = nested_map_as_in_the_config_file

zipmap prompts an error if there is a nested value.

Comment: So can you provide actual, fully reproducable code? What errors do you get? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: So you can provide actual error message showing exact line the error occurrs? ALso where and how do you use your zipmap? Your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: We definitely need more information to fill in the gaps here, but in general this is solved in most languages by dumping out to a string format that supports complex structures e.g. YAML, JSON, etc. and then parsing the output in the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the YAML variable is a map/list of objects itself, this is how I convert it into a string:

```
default-params:
  arg1: rds_db
  arg2: rds_cat_name

   schemas:
     schema_1: schema_name_1
     schema_2: schema_name_2

  rds_input_table_list: 
      - database: db_name
        schema: schema_name
        table: table_name
      - database: db_name
        schema: schema_name
        table: table_name
  rds_output_table: output_table
  # # --SQL
  sql: |
    This is the SQL definition for each job
  sql_type: sparksql

join(";", [ for par in local.param.other-params: join(",", tolist( [for key, value in par: format("%s=%s",key,value)])) ])
```

If you still think there is a better approach to converting such lists into a string, please advise.